# How to read an uploaded CSV file in ASP.NET and skip the first line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, csv, file-io

I am able to read a CSV file and work with it when the file is stored locally.
Here I have the path from the file which is stored on my PC.
I want to skip the first line in the csv and only read the following lines and store them.
For that I use the following snippet and it works fine.

```
public void ReadCSV(string path)
{
     var data = File.ReadAllLines(path)
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(x => x.Split(';'))
             //.....
 }
```

If the file is stored locally I can read it and work with it, means I am able to skip the first line and store the values into objects.
But I don't know how to work with a file which come from the frontend.

I tested it with Postman (upload a file) and made an endpoint which is able to read the uploaded file.

I used `IFormFile`

```
public async Task<string> ReadFileAsStrintAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                    result.AppendLine(await reader.ReadLineAsync());
            }

           return result.toString();
        }
```

This will send me the content of the csv as a string.

My problem is now I cannot use the LINQ statement like `.Skip` and `.Select` as this is not an `IEnumerable`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IFormFile has method OpenReadSteam and CopyTo. Use those methods and [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0#constructors). It has a bunch of usefull methods for work. Try to figure it out yourself and then come back if you'll get stuck

Comment: I can read the file with OpenReadStream and with the while loop I'm basically reading all line like in the first snippet but then I need like Select and Skip which is not available for IFormFile only for System.IO File. So, do I need to convert or so?

Comment: In StreamReader there is a constructor that accepts a Stream also there is a method ReadToEnd that reads stream to end and returns a string which is IEnumerable, so you can use LINQ. You can split that string by '\n' (end of line) and you will get an array of strings like if you use File.ReadAllLines()

Comment: You really shouldn't be parsing CSV yourself anyways. Use a dedicated library that understands the nuances, such as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> My problem is now I cannot use the LINQ statement like .Skip and .Select as this is not an IEnumerable.

So let's create a method that takes as input a TextReader (your StreamReader is a TextReader) and that returns a sequence of lines.

I'll create it as an extension method, so you can use it as if it was a LINQ method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToLines(this TextReader textReader)
{
    string line = textReader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        // we've read a line; return it
        yield return line;
        // read the next line or null if there is no next line:
        line = textReader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string csvFileName = ...
string name = ....
using (var textReader = File.OpenText(csvFileName))
{
    var firstLineThatContainsNane = textReader.ToLines()
        .Skip(1)
        .Where(line => line.Contains(name))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The nice thing is, that if you only want to read a few lines, not the whole file is read!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the best way to read a CSV is using an existing library. Is easier to implement, read the code, safer and you ensure it will work perfectly.

But if you want to create your own method to create the CSV then you have to know that the String returned by the frontend is this... only a simple String.

You have to split to get the different values. I assume your string will be differents lines, so you can split by `\n` and then you have a `string[]` object... the same as using `File.ReadAllLines()`. So the rest of the code is the same.

Also I've tested this code:

```cs
string str = "li;ne1\nli;ne2\nli;ne3";
var data = str.Split('\n').Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(";"));
```

And works perfectly. And make sense because is do the same operation over the same object type.

So, your problem is String is not an `IEnumerable`. So you have to transform as `IEnumerable` using, for example, `Split()`.

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I already achieved. I could split the string but only when the csv is read from my disk but I have no clue how to handle a file which come from the frontend. How can I convert the IFormFile into a string into a IEnumerable?

Comment: What's the retrurn from `ReadFileAsStrintAsync()` method? Is the CSV as String? And you can't split by lines?

Comment: The CSV has 2 lines and the `ReadFileAsStrintAsync()` methods return a string. It takes a file from type IFormFile and will read the file and save the content into a string. Here my problem starts. I can't figure out the next step. In the first snippet `File.ReadAllLines()` read all the lines and store it in a string[] array which is exactly what I want! But I don't know how to apply this logic for the second snippet... I want to store the result into a string[] as well for each line and not a single string if possible

Comment: Can you post an example of the string returned by `ReadFileAsStrintAsync`?

Comment: ```Line0: id,lastName,firstName,age \n
Line1: 0,doe,jon,20```

this is the output, so it does do Lines but why I can't use `Split()` then? Is there something I'm missing?